# Calling a SP from another SP via EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL` for calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure but I am getting an error. I haven't tried it before so I don't know what is wrong.

Here `SPGetServiceState` is SP and `@Id(IN), @Return_State(OUT), @Return_Execute_Date(OUT)` are parameters needed to pass and `@Request_Id` has id needed to pass.

```
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL N'SPGetServiceState', N'@Id int,
  @Return_State tinyint, @Return_Execute_Date smalldatetime', 
  @Id = @Request_Id, @Return_State = 0, @Return_Execute_Date = NULL
```

Comment: Why do you use `sp_executesql`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Actually I read on a bolg that EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL is more effective than exec. SO thought I should try the better one.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link to the blog?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/02/sql-server-2005-comparison-sp_executesql-vs-executeexec/

Comment: That is true for dynamic SQL not for calling a stored procedure as you do here. The procedure will be parameterized even if you use `exec`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, Oh I really don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you retrieve the name of the stored procedure from a variable, there is no need for dynamic SQL. You can just:

```
exec dbo.SPGetServiceState(@Id, @Return_State output, @Return_Execute_Date output);
```

Don't forget the `output` specifier.  Without it, the parameter is treated as an input parameter.

Comment: Actually I read on a bolg that EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL is more effective than exec. SO thought I should try the better one.

Comment: @ITBeginner: `sp_executesql` is better than `exec` for dynamic SQL.  But you don't need dynamic SQL to call a stored procedure.

Comment: Even if the stored procedure name is in a variable, you still don't need dynamic SQL: `exec @StoredProcedureNameInAVariable` works fine.